# Proving this complex function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function such that $g(z)=f(1/z)$, $z\in C\setminus \{0\}$ has a removable singularity at 0. Show that $f$ is constant.

I think this has to be proved by Liouville's theorem by showing that $f$ is bounded in $C$. Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: what if $g(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}$?!

Comment: @slader.com Since when ${1 \over z}$ has removable singularity in $0$?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant $f(z)=1/z$, then $g(z)=z$

Comment: @slader.com in that case $f$ is not entire.

Comment: didn't pay attention to that part, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Since $g$ has removable singularity at $0$ there exists a real number $M_1$ such that $|g(z)| =|f(z^{-1} ) |< M_1 $  for $|z|\leq 1$ but this means that $|f(u)|\leq M_1 $ for $|u|\geq 1.$ Moreover since $f$ is entire there exists a real number $M_2$ such that $|f(z)|< M_1 $  for $|z|\leq 1. $ Therefore $f$ is bounded.